# How to generate interface (not dispinterface) for Automation events

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to create an automation server with events. This server is to match a client which is already developed. Here is the event handing part of the *_TLB.Pas file of the client.

```
 ILocationMapServiceEvents = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{F03C34F5-CDD3-4558-8895-1A81C535CD8F}']
    procedure OnFormClosed; safecall;
    procedure OnMapCaptured(const mapState: WideString; mapImage: PSafeArray); safecall;
  end;

ILocationMapServiceEventsDisp = dispinterface
    ['{F03C34F5-CDD3-4558-8895-1A81C535CD8F}']
    procedure OnFormClosed; dispid 1;
    procedure OnMapCaptured(const mapState: WideString; 
                            mapImage: {NOT_OLEAUTO(PSafeArray)}OleVariant); dispid 2;
  end;
```

But when I try to generate event supported code (by clicking "Generate Event Support Code in Delphi Automation Object dialog) it only generates the `dispinterface`.

```
ILocationMapServiceEventsDisp = dispinterface
    ['{F03C34F5-CDD3-4558-8895-1A81C535CD8F}']
    procedure onFormClosed; dispid 1;
    procedure onMapCaptured(const mapState: WideString;
                            mapImage: {NOT_OLEAUTO(PSafeArray)}OleVariant); dispid 2;
  end;
```

How to get Delphi (Mine XE5) to generate event supported code with both interface and dispinterface.

My real problem is that I can send a PSafeArray through dispinterface.

UPDATE:

This link shows someone else who has the exact same problem. But the answer doesn't work either.

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21466789/COM-events-with-out-using-dispinterface.html

Comment: Why not just copy paste from the client?

Comment: Tried that. But it fails when firing the event.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem. But I think you can re-create the interface manually in the type library editor, or by copy-pasting the relevant part into the .ridl.file.

Comment: The original automation server is written in C#. I have the DLL. So I can see type library. Now I need to develop this in Delphi. The problem arises when I try to generate the event supported automation server. It generates dispinterface for the events. But the original type library has interface (duel in fact) for the events. It fails when I manually add interface and try to fire events with the same guid. I updated the question with a similar link.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It says catastrophic failure.